Github Pages not recognizing Angular routing
I have a test Angular18 website hosted on Github Pages. I have an About page that works perfectly on my localhost, but came back as 404 not found. I created a 404.html file as suggested in many posts, but it has only led to a blank screen instead. I added debugging code to log the route in console and nothing comes up. Why is Github Pages not recognizing my different routes?
Main.yml
name: Deploy Angular to GitHub Pages

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Setup Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 18

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install

      - name: Build the Angular app
        run: npm run build -- --output-path=dist/angular-page --base-href="/angular-page/"

      - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
        uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@v4
        with:
          folder: dist/angular-page/browser  # Corrected the folder path
          branch: gh-pages
          token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}  # Use default GITHUB_TOKEN unless using custom


app.routes.ts
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent }, // Root route displays Home
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent }, // About route
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' } // Wildcard route redirects to Home
];


What is working and what is not working? could you please elaborate more?

The home page works, while the about page does not work. Precisely, it seems like the 404.html runs when https://cherryleh.github.io/angular-page/about is accessed and the routing is not acknowledged or found in my app.

Try to add <base href="/angular-page/"> in your main.html file

Hi Ramesh. I added it to my index.html, but unfortunately nothing has changed. It is also worth noting that the app is deployed to my gh-pages branch, where index.html already had the snippet <base href="/angular-page/"> as well
